# http request does not get called when uploading the data to Firebase - firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, httprequest

Hello everyone I am trying to fetch the data from Binance than do a schedule function that uploads the data from the previous fetch to the Cloud FireStore , the schedule function is a function that gets called every minute and MUST call the fetch function update the object that contain the data and than I parse that object in order to upload the updated data.

The problem is that the function that fetches the data gets called just one time and that is it, the next minute after the function deploy the fetch data gets not called and I tried everything I found on stackoverflow and google but not luck.

Can anyone give me a hint thank you.

Code:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {value: true});
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const https = require("https");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();
let finalData = [];
const page = 1;
const fiat = "RON";
const tradeType = "SELL";
const asset = "USDT";
const payTypes = ["BCRBank"];
const baseObj = {
  page,
  rows: 20,
  publisherType: null,
  asset,
  tradeType,
  fiat,
  payTypes,
};
const stringData = JSON.stringify(baseObj);
const options = {
  hostname: "p2p.binance.com",
  port: 443,
  path: "/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": stringData.length,
  },
};

finalData = [];
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log("Entered the request call");
  let output = "";
  res.on("data", (d) => {
    output += d;
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
    try {
      const jsonOuput = JSON.parse(output);
      const allData = jsonOuput["data"];
      for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
        let payTypesz = "";
        for (let y = 0; y < allData[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"].length; y++) {
          payTypesz += allData[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"][y]["payType"];
          if (y < allData[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"].length - 1) {
            payTypesz += ", ";
          }
        }
        const obj = {
          tradeType: allData[i]["adv"]["tradeType"],
          asset: allData[i]["adv"]["asset"],
          fiatUnit: allData[i]["adv"]["fiatUnit"],
          price: allData[i]["adv"]["price"],
          surplusAmount: allData[i]["adv"]["surplusAmount"],
          maxSingleTransAmount: allData[i]["adv"]["maxSingleTransAmount"],
          minSingleTransAmount: allData[i]["adv"]["minSingleTransAmount"],
          nickName: allData[i]["advertiser"]["nickName"],
          monthOrderCount: allData[i]["advertiser"]["monthOrderCount"],
          monthFinishRate: allData[i]["advertiser"]["monthFinishRate"],
          advConfirmTime: allData[i]["advertiser"]["advConfirmTime"],
          payTypes: payTypesz,
          position: 0,
        };
        finalData.push(obj);
      }
      console.log(finalData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});

const fD =function fetchData(stringData) {
  console.log("I entered the FetchData");
  req.write(stringData);
};

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("* * * * *")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
      console.log("I am doing it");
      fD(stringData);
      for (let i = 0; i < finalData.length; i++) {
        console.log("I did not entered here");
        console.log(finalData[i]["price"]);
        await database.collection("SebiBinanceSale").doc("BCR Bank")
            .collection("1").doc(i.toString())
            .set({
              "tradeType": finalData[i]["tradeType"],
              "asset": finalData[i]["asset"],
              "fiatUnit": finalData[i]["fiatUnit"],
              "price": finalData[i]["price"],
              "surplusAmount": finalData[i]["surplusAmount"],
              "maxSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["maxSingleTransAmount"],
              "minSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["minSingleTransAmount"],
              "nickName": finalData[i]["nickName"],
              "monthOrderCount": finalData[i]["monthOrderCount"],
              "monthFinishRate": finalData[i]["monthFinishRate"],
              "advConfirmTime": finalData[i]["advConfirmTime"],
              "payTypes": finalData[i]["payTypes"],
              "position": finalData[i]["position"],
            });
      }
      return console.log("Succes Upload of the data ");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some of the magic incantation here:

```
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
```

According to the Firebase documentation on [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) that should be:

```
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
```

Comment: But would the fetch data save the data inside the finalData object that in the end will be used by the schedule function ? If yes than it is amazing otherwise it won't work since the second function or the schedule function won't have data to upload data to firebase

Comment: and I don't think it is possible to call the schedule function and inside it call the http.request

Comment: In that case I might not understand what the `const req = https.request(options, (res) => {` function is meant to do. Is it relevant to the problem?

Comment: So the block of code that starts with const req = https... does a call to fetch the data, it receives the data and than from the Json parses it and I build a list called finalData. finalData list contains the objects that I need to upload to the cloud Firestone.  My scheduleFunction MUST call this req http request every minute in order to update the object FinalData and than upload the new data.  Hope I explained myself

Comment: I updated the code with some comments in order to make myself clear

Comment: It sounds like the code that is inside `const req = https.request(options, (res) => {` should be inside the scheduled Cloud Function instead, or at least be called from there. Since you now have it as its own top-level code, it just gets run once when the container loads not on the schedule of your Cloud Function.

Comment: I updated the code as you suggested but still the fetchData does not get called and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the function work and callable every minute you have to use the promise otherwise it won't work. Once I start using the promise it star working right away.

code below :

```
const fD = function fetchData(stringData) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    console.log("I entered the FetchData");
    req.write(stringData);
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Based on the doc, this line `.schedule("* * * * *")` should probably be `.schedule("1 * * * *")` if you want it to run every minute.

Comment: Nope, 1 * * * * means minute one of every hour. I suggest you check out the following link : https://crontab.guru/#1_*_*_*_*.  + I fixed the problem in the end. In 7 days the bounty will expire and nobody will get the 50 points.